# 'Unity Quit Unexpectedly' when trying to build to iOS

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, build, crash, exit

I have made a project, and it has been working fine for the past month or so, and I would regularly build it to my iPad and play my game, but just recently when I changed my materials to `Legacy` and imported an asset, I am not able to build to iOS any more.

I changed all the materials back and deleted the assets, but I cannot build my project to `Xcode`. If I call the project a certain name - `CuboidT2` - it crashes, but if I use another name, it just does nothing: it does not build or anything and the build window just stays there. It does not show any errors, and I have done nothing different (anything that I did do different I changed back).

I don't know what's happening. If you want any extra information please let me know.

Comment: Yeah I think more information would be nice.  The stacktrace for starters.

Comment: How do you get a stack trace in Unity?

Comment: You're not in Unity; you get it the same way you get a stracktrace from any iOS app.

Comment: I cannot build it to my iPad. When I click build IN unity, it crashes unity.

Comment: OK, sounds like a support issue then.  You need to report it to Unity.

Comment: Ok thanks for your help.

Comment: Always helps to be on the latest Unity release, which is 5.2.2 as of yesterday.